# Spring + Kubernetes minikube: Redirects work not as expected

Tags: spring-boot, redirect, spring-cloud, minikube

I am learning the kubernetes using minikube and come up with idea to create simple service which will shorten my very long links. The service locally is working fine, but when I create a pod of that service in my cluster it's still working fine, but the redirect mechanism which spring provide in it's MVC module does not work as expected. While I try to redirect to an external URL e.g.

```
@GetMapping("/google")
public String redirectToGoogle(){
return "redirect:www.google.com"
}
```

it is redirecting me instead to "MINIKUBE_IP/www.google.pl".

What could cause that behaviour? It that somehow configurable?
Could you guide me how to solve that issue? If there will be a need to add anything I will do that with pleasure. I will attache the Deployment and the Service resources of my service.

For the first time I thought it's issue with Ingress, but tried it without ingress using simple port-forward but the issue it the same.

Using port-forward, NodePorts on services does not work either.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: link-shortener
  labels:
    app: link-shortener
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: link-shortener
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: link-shortener
  labels:
    app: link-shortener
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: link-shortener
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: link-shortener
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: link-shortener
        image: link-shortener
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
        env:
        - name: MONGO_DATABASE
          valueFrom:
            configMapKeyRef:
              name: mongodb
              key: database-name
        - name: MONGO_USERNAME
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb
              key: database-user
        - name: MONGO_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongodb
              key: database-password
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found how to deal with it. When I redirect to an adress with *http://* or *https://* prefixes it is working as intended. So I will just create validator which will check if these prefixes even exists before redirecting.